# trouble creating a pulling force and change the force with Mouse_Event

Tags: actionscript-3, rotation, mouseevent, physics

Hey everyone so I've been at this for awhile now and finally decided to ask for some help. So I am creating a game in AS3 where the `object` rotates in a circular motion from either left to right depending on the users mouse Presses. So I have some variables set up to act as friction. What I AM trying to accomplish is when the `object` is greater or less than a certain rotation degree I want the object to feel like it being pulled more and more to that side that it is currently at and the only way the object can say come back to its original position is if the use clicks on the mouse enough so their is no more force acting on it and say the speed increases at the same time for difficulty.

Here are the Variables I am currently working with:

```
        //Variables
        speed = 0.2;
        vx = 0;
        friction = 0.93;
        maxspeed = 10;
```

I also have these buttons on stage so the user can click them to change the rotation of the `object`like so:

```
    mainScreen.leftBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, leftButtonClicked);
    mainScreen.rightBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, rightButtonClicked);

private function leftButtonClicked(e:MouseEvent):void 
    {
        clickLeft = true;
        clickRight = false;
    }

    private function rightButtonClicked(e:MouseEvent):void 
    {
        clickRight = true;
        clickLeft = false;
    }
```

and I try to set up the mechanics in my ENTER_FRAME event listener like so:

```
//RIGHT = CLOCKWISE +, Left = COUNTER CLOCKWISE  -
        if (clickRight)
        {
            vx += speed;
            moveSlow = true;
            moveFast = false;
        }else
        if (clickLeft)
        {
            vx -= speed;
            moveSlow = true;
            moveFast = false;
        }else           
        {
            vx *= friction;
        }

        //IF object is Past 15 Degrees make object go faster MOVE FAST
        if (object.rotation > 15)
        {
            moveFast = true;
            moveSlow = false;
            trace("MOVE_FAST");
        }else
        if (object.rotation < - 15)
        {
            moveFast = true;
            moveSlow = false;
        }else           
        {
            vx *= friction;
        }

         object.rotation += vx;
        //lumberJack.rotation += speed;

        //boundaries of object
        if (vx > maxspeed)
            vx = maxspeed;
        else if (vx < -maxspeed)
            vx = -maxspeed;
```

I know I need to add something in the if `object.rotation` statement but not to sure what i also know i need to add something in the Mouse clicked event listeners to manipulate either speed or friction so the user can pull away from the force acting on it. I tried several time but still cant seem to figure it out. As of now the object rotates left or right depending on the users input and say the object is moving left and the user presses right the `object` slowly moves back to the left then returns to normal speed.

Please If anyone can help me figure this out I will greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Are you trying to make an object of yours behave like a wheel that has its mass center off the axis? You will probably have to implement a bit of physics calculations to perform this.

Comment: Yeah thats pretty much what I am trying to accomplish thanks vesper. Ill go check if i can find some tutorials.

Comment: There is a game that has the mechanics im trying to implement. If I send you a link think you can help me out to get a better idea of what i mean?

Answer (score 1):

To be honest I am having a little bit of trouble following your question, so this may only be a partial answer. I know, bad me, but I don't have enough stupid internet points to leave a comment, so this is all I can do to help, and I just can't care about the internet point system anymore.

First, for the love of *insert deity*, clean up all that unnecessary white space.

Here's a potential problem in your code: the `rotation` property of display objects returns a value between `-180` and `180`. This means that every 180 degrees, the rotation value changes sign. So you can't use whether the rotation is positive or negative to determine which direction the object is rotating in. That should be stored in a separate variable.

Another thing to consider: if moveSlow and moveFast are never true at the same time, you don't need to have two variables because it's redundant. You don't make use of those variables in your code above, but assuming you wrote this:

```
if (moveSlow) {
    moveALittleBit();
} else if (moveFast) {
    moveALot();
}
```

You could replace it with:

```
if (moveSlow) {
    moveALittleBit();
} else {
    moveALot();
}
```

Not only is that giving yourself unnecessary work, but it's bad because it means you can create "invalid states" (i.e. if you make a mistake and "moveSlow" and "moveFast" are both true at the same time).

Likewise, you shouldn't need separate variables for "clickedLeft" and "clickedRight" if they are both mutually exclusive. If they can both be false at the same time, however, you might be better off with something like:

```
clickDirection = "left";
clickDirection = "right";
clickDirection = "none";
```

If you went that route, you'd be better off using string constants instead of hardcoded strings, but I think that's getting too off-topic.

After reading your question many times, it sounds like maybe what you are looking for is momentum. Does this cover what you need?

```
if (clickRight)
{
    vx += speed;
    momentum = 0;
} else if (clickLeft)
{
    vx -= speed;
    momentum = 0;
} else     
{
    vx *= friction;
}

//IF object is Past 15 Degrees make object go faster MOVE FAST
if (object.degreesRotated > 15)
{
    momentum += 1;
}else if (object.degreesRotated < - 15)
{
    momentum -= 1;
}else           
{
    vx *= friction;
}

vx += momentum;
object.rotation += vx;
object.degreesRotated += vx; //remember how much we've rotated
//lumberJack.rotation += speed;
```

If object is a dynamic type, you can add the "degreesRotated" property whenever you feel like it. Otherwise, you might have to make a new class by extending whatever display type that object is, and add the degreesRotated field to that class

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response Ill definately take a look into this and see how it turns out. Ill get back to you if i have questions thanks

Comment: No problem, I hope that helps you out.